# Ajax Load is working recursive in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have used the ajax load function inside the setTimeout while page loading,the ajax load function will be called after the particular time,

The thing is that its been working after the setTimeout completed. Its working like the recursive.

SetTimeout Function will be called once, but if i used ajax function inside it. Its working recursively.

```
 var pathname = window.location.pathname;
 setTimeout(function(){
   $('body').load(pathname + '#examplediv');
 },60000);
```

How to stop calling recursively for ajax load?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184616/discussion-on-question-by-logesh-ajax-load-is-working-recursive-in-settimeout).

Answer (score 0):

From the conversation in comments I have guess a solution. It may be the exact solution for you. But some time will work for others.
When I loaded a page named "ABC" through Ajax by clicking a button/link. And from that "ABC" page calling the   $('body').load(url). The $('body').load(url) was as many times as I clicked the button/link.
Reading from the internet I learned I need unbind the event I created. So I used this just loading the page by ajax. 
So, I just used method. And it's solved my problem.

```
$("body").unbind(); 
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
 setTimeout(function(){
   $('body').load(pathname + '#examplediv');
 },60000);
```

Comment: @logesh Of course this won't work because this isn't the issue in your situation. That's why I don't answer your question and only make a lot of comments. You first need to understand exactly what's going on and only _then_ you can provide an answer.

Comment: Its not working, I created the new page and done the same like you said. But the page is still loading for every one minute

Comment: @logesh the page you loading again does it contain the same  setTimeout(function(){ function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to load a specific element inside a file through Ajax. That's not possible. Ajax loads the entire file you're pointing it to. In your case, the file is your own index file, which also includes the `setTimeout` function. Hence it keeps on reloading every minute.

To solve this issue, create a new file like `popup.html` for example. Copy the code inside `#examplediv` towards this new file. Then remove it from your index file. Now use:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').load(pathname + '/popup.html');
},60000);
```

Ajax will now load `popup.html` after 1 minute (which only contains the code from `#examplediv`) into your `body` element instead of your entire own index file. That will solve the problem.

Comment: The thing is popup will be shown in all the page. Can I load the same page alone?

Comment: Even I want just to refresh the page using ajax. But the page should be reloaded

Comment: @logesh You can load whatever you want. Just copy / paste the code you wish to load inside `popup.html` and it will be loaded in. Just make sure you don't copy the timeout itself. That's what's causing your issue.